# metre package: \tie and \itie print numbers

Tags: metre

I am struggling with a LaTeX [metre](https://mirror.szerverem.hu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/metre/metre.pdf) package for annotating classical poetry. When I try to use elision with

> \itie

command, I get numbers printed out before the tie as in the following example:
[image]

Expected behavior is 'Libatum agricolae' with a tie between 'm' at the end of the first word and an 'a' at the beginning of the next one.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[en]{metre}

\begin{document}

\textbf{1st problem:}\par
\vspace{10}
Libatu\itie{m a}gricolae\par
\vspace{10}
Libatu\tie{m a}gricolae\par

\end{document}
```

The same behavior is observed when I write out metre and enlarge the symbols with '\m4'.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\usepackage[en]{metre}

\begin{document}
\textbf{2nd problem:}\par
\vspace{10}
\metra[\m4]{\M\bbm\v\M\bbm\v\M\bbm\v\M\bbm\v\M\b\b\v\M\a}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this behavior of this admittedly obscure package? Compilers pdfLatex and Xetex will both compile this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally the `metre` package uses the `\relsize` command from the `relsize` package to loop over all possible font sizes in order to calculate the size of the ties.

To make sure the font starts as small as possible the command `\relsize{-10}` is used, i.e., decrease the font size with 10 steps. For default font sizes this would normally trigger a warning, because 10 steps smaller from a normal size is not available. In the `metre` package this warning is suppressed by redefining `\rs@size@warning` to be `\relax` (i.e., to print nothing).

However, since `metre` was written (in 2001) the syntax of `\rs@size@warning` has changed, instead of two parameters there are now three parameters. The original redefinition is `\renewcommand{\rs@size@warning}[2]{\relax}`, so it changes the command from three parameters (in the `relsize` source) to two parameters. But, when the warning is actually called by `relsize`, three parameters are supplied, with as third parameter the font size that is used instead of the requested size. The redefined command takes the first two parameters, executes `\relax`, and then LaTeX processes the third parameter, which is now just a token that gets printed.

To fix this issue you can provide a new redefinition with three parameters. Because the warning command contains the `@` symbol you need to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` before and after the redefinition.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{metre}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\rs@size@warning}[3]{\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textbf{1st problem:}\par
Libatu\itie{m a}gricolae

\vspace{10pt}
Libatu\tie{m a}gricolae\par

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem! And thanks for the detailed explanation about the dependencies.